# Assigning a pointer to a pointer in C results in a null pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

In C, I am creating a datastructure that includes an array of pointers to another structure. The array is defined like this (the structure is called `Bucket`).

```
Bucket *b_array[];
```

This array is part of another structure, called `Object` for the sake of this question. The entire `typedef` then looks like this:

```
typedef struct Object {
    Bucket *b_array[];
} Object;
```

Now, a bit further in the program, I am using this array and I am trying to create a variable that holds a pointer to one of the buckets in the array. The function gets a pointer to an `Object` structure (`obj_ptr`)and the index (`idx`) of the bucket. The code looks as follows:

```
Bucket *at_idx = *(obj_ptr->b_array + idx);
```

Here is the problem: Upon executing this code, the `at_idx` variable becomes a null pointer. GDB can confirm this for me.

```
(gdb) p at_idx
$1 = (Bucket *) 0x0
```

However, the thing that I am trying to assign to `at_idx` is not null. This is also something that GDB can confirm. Even weirder, the exact same expression is used in an `if`-statement a couple lines earlier where I check `*(obj_ptr->b_array + idx) == NULL` and that returns false.

I am out of ideas of what is going on here, but it will probably be something simple that I'm missing.

Any help will be appreciated!

*I am sorry for the possibly vague context of the code, but this issue is happening in a university assignment. Because of university policy I am not allowed to share my full code.*

Comment: When did you allocate memory ?

Comment: @MaartenWeyns "*Because of university policy I am not allowed to share my full code*" - then provide a separate [mcve] that demonstrates the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct Object {
    Bucket *b_array[];
} Object;
```

First of all C does allow variable size arrays in empty structures.

```
typedef struct Object {
    int a;
    Bucket *b_array[];
} Object;
```

You need to allocate memory for the variable size array (and the structure itself as well).

```
Object *obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj) + NELEMENTS * sizeof(obj -> b_array[0]));
```

Then you may start to assign the values to the array.